# CXF RESTful: No message body reader has been found for request class, ContentType : application/json

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I have to implement a REST service with CXF 2.7.11, the service already implements a WS-SOAP Service.

I'm getting the error "No message body reader has been found for request class MyRequest, ContentType : application/json".

I'm trying the following implementation:

```
@Path("/myService")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    @POST
    @Path("/myOperation")
    public MyResponse myOperation(MyRequest request){
        // my implementation
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
8-feb-2018 17.12.15 org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request class MyRequest, ContentType : application/json.
8-feb-2018 17.12.15 org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1231)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:756)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:715)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:252)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:88)
     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
     at it.prometeia.hnwi.searchengine.configuration.filter.CustomMonitoringFilter.doFilter(CustomMonitoringFilter.java:33)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The error means that there is no `MessageBodyReader` registered in CXF.

Since I'm not using Spring and I don't have an ApplicationContext, I solved it as follows:

```
private void createService(Class<?> serviceClass, String address, Object serviceImpl) {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean srvFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    srvFactory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);
    srvFactory.setAddress("/rest"+address);
    srvFactory.setServiceBean(serviceImpl);
    srvFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new CustomInInterceptor());
    srvFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomOutInterceptor());
    srvFactory.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    srvFactory.create();
}
```

I needed to register a Provider, for which I used `JacksonJsonProvider` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solution will work for everyone or not but this is how I solved it.

My `MyRequest` class was initially like this:

```
@Data
public class MyRequest {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
}
```

`@Data` is a Lombok annotation that provides the Getters, Setters, and toString method to the class.

I updated `MyRequest` class with these annotations:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "myRequest")
public class MyRequest {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
}
```

That is I have added these 3 following new annotations to my class and it solved the issue.
`@NoArgsConstructor` 
`@AllArgsConstructor` 
`@XmlRootElement`

@NoArgsConstructor is a Lombok annotation that creates a no-argument constructor. 
@AllArgsConstructor is a Lombok annotation that creates an all-argument constructor. 
@XmlRootElement is from javax.xml.bind package and it causes a global element declaration to be produced in the schema. The global element declaration is associated with the XML schema type to which the class is mapped.

Although I didn't get the time to seclude each of the 3 annotations one by one to see which one actually fixed this issue but my hunch is adding the `@XmlRootElement` annotation might have fixed this issue for me.